# MacBook Pro external display support (different resolution from notebook display)

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, displayport, resolution, vga-adapter

My MacBook Pro has a Mini DisplayPort and running Snow Leopard. I'm looking to get myself a Mini DisplayPort -> VGA adapter so that I can attach a hand-me-down LCD display. The LCD display has a native resolution of 1280 x 1024.

Can the MacBook Pro use both displays at once, with the main notebook display at 1280x800 and the external display at 1280x1024?

In general, can the Mini DisplayPort output a resolution different from the main notebook display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, mismatched resolutions are no problem. I'm running a similar set up right now. You can arrange them however you like in the Displays section of System Preferences.